# Firebase: Nodes are getting replaced by commas after deleting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a webshop. When a product is deleted from the shopping cart, a firebase function must be triggered to recalculate the new total price of all the files remaining in the cart.

```
export const onProductDelete = functions.database
.ref(`/orders/{userID}/{orderID}/products/{productID}`)
.onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
...
})
```

When a product is deleted (manually in the Firebase realtime database dashboard or programmatically) the firebase function gets called but the price doesn't get updated because the amount of products is the same (?).

I logged the array of products in the function and this is the result:

```
products: [
  ,
  { test: 'test' },
  ,
  ,
  { test: 'test' } 
]
```

The deleted products are not visible in the database but are replaced with commas and are still being counted as a product (object)

Anyone an idea what is happening?

**Update with extra information**

complete firebase function

```
export const onProductDelete = functions.database.ref(`/orders/{userID}/{orderID}/products/{productsID}`).onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
  try {
    const userID = context.params.userID;
    const orderID = context.params.orderID;
    const productID = context.params.productID;

    const orderSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(`orders/${userID}/${orderID}`).once('value');
    const orderData = orderSnapshot.val();

    console.log('products: ', orderData.products); // products: [, { test: 'test' }, , , { test: 'test' }]

    const amountOfProducts = orderData.products.length;
    const newSubTotal = amountOfProducts * 100; //Fixed product price for example
    const taxes = newSubTotal * 0.10; //Fixed tax of 10% for example
    const total = newSubTotal + taxes;

    return admin.database().ref(`orders/${userID}/${orderID}/price`).set({ amountOfProducts, subTotal: newSubTotal, taxes, total });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('Error in onProductDelete: ', error);
    return null;
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the entire code of your Cloud Function? How exactly do you log the array of products in the function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've added the entire Cloud Function. I'm logging the array of products just after `const orderData = orderSnapshot.val();` with the following code `console.log('products: ', orderData.products);`

Comment: if I understand correctly, there are two different nodes implied in the Cloud Function: `/products/{userID}/{productID}/files/{fileID}` on one hand (where you delete) and `orders/${userID}/${orderID}` on another hand, that you read. Is that right?

Comment: Correct but I made a mistake while copying the code. The first node (where I delete) should be `/orders/{userID}/{orderID}/products/{productsID}`

Comment: So the idea is that the listener is checking if a product gets deleted. If that's happening, the price should be recalculated based on the remaining products. To make it more simple for the question I edited the calculation part to a fixed price.

Comment: Give me some few minutes, trying to reproduce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186594/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-thore).

Comment: Something a bit different but why do you re-calculate the total after a delete? Can't you just simply substract the deleted value from the total? In that case you won't have to read the entire list every time and it might save you a lot of database actions and thus money if you are on a paid plan. Take a look at [this costly mistake](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: @AndréKool A user can add a coupon code to their order. This coupon code is validated (email and enterprise number has to match) once in another cloud function and the corresponding data (discount percentage and minimum value) is added to the order node.

Every time a product is added/deleted, the discount and price are recalculated and updated in the database (this code part is not involved in the code example).On the client side I'm using an child listener to check for price changes.

I couldn't figure out another save way to do this without using a cloud function. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to come from the fact that you write a set of products as an array. When you read the array in the Cloud Function (which is triggered when a value of the array is deleted), the array returned by the `once()` method is not correct, e.g; `[, { test: 'test' }, , , { test: 'test' }]` instead of `[{ test: 'test' }, { test: 'test' }]`

If you write your product set as an object, you will get a correct `products` object.

You may use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) method to write you `products` object, letting Firebase generating unique ids for the products.